# try-runtime: Found argument 'ws://localhost:9944' which wasn't expected

Tags: try-runtime

I run the following command:

```
cargo run --release --features=try-runtime try-runtime on-runtime-upgrade live ws://localhost:9944
```

And I get the error:

```
error: Found argument 'ws://localhost:9944' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

As the help message says:

```
USAGE:
    substrate try-runtime on-runtime-upgrade live [OPTIONS] --uri <URI>
```

use the `--uri` flag:

```
cargo run --release --features=try-runtime try-runtime on-runtime-upgrade live --uri ws://localhost:9944
```